# Meteor preventDefault() function not working

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

So I am having this issue where prevent default is not working on my web application. Js I am very new to meteor. Here is my body.js

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import '../body.html';

Template.newround.events({
  'submit .new-round'(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log("test");
  },
});
```

just ask if you need any other info.

HTML:

```
<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; min-height: 100%;">

      <div class="col-md-3"><!--  --></div>

      <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h1 class="center-text">Welcome to FightBot!</h1>
            <p class="center-text">With FightBot you can increase your reaction time! Lets begin!</p>
          </div>

          <hr>

          <div class="panel-body">

            {{> newround }}

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3"><!--  --></div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

<template name="newround">

<form class="new-round">

  <p>Seconds between strikes:</p>

  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="seconds">

  <br>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="Start">

</form>

</template>
```

That's all the html if anything else is needed just ask.

Comment: So what behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well

Comment: at the end of the url its doing the following: ?seconds=121

Comment: html posted for you. @NicholasByDesign

Comment: Works for me, however what happens if you remove the imports at the top of your js file?  Those are not required (despite the Meteor docs, unless you are using modules)  and did cause a bug for me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that newround is a template that contain a form, and event.preventDefault() should prevent the default behavior (preventing the form from being submitted).  It assume that you will handle the submission yourself.  The console.log("test") line should still get executed.  What is not working?